# Loop over dataframe, calculate correlation between columns for unique values of column?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe that looks like this (but longer...):

```
    imd     code       sum
0     1    010101   1048171
1     2    010101    911003
2     3    010101    852023
3     4    010101    790893
4     5    010101    923344
5     6    010101    681473
6     7    010101    600303
7     8    010101    497439
8     9    010101    496209
9    10    010101    388457
10    1    010102  26284506
11    2    010102  23567345
12    3    010102  24933988
13    4    010102  22762737
14    5    010102  23205722
15    6    010102  21874259
16    7    010102  21604496
17    8    010102  16723338
18    9    010102  17691183
19   10    010102  15202808
```

Now I want to calculate the correlation between `imd` and `sum` *for every unique value of `code` in the dataframe*. So in this example, the correlation between `imd` and `sum` for code `010101`, then for code `010102`, etc.

Then I want to produce a ranked list of the codes with the highest correlations. So something like this:

```
  code    correlation
  010102  0.44
  010101  0.38
  ....
```

What's the best way to do this? I know how to calculate the correlation between `imd` and `sum` for the whole dataframe:

```
df[['imd','sum']].corr()
```

but not how to do it repeatedly for each slice of the dataframe that is a unique code.

I guess I could create a new dataframe for each unique value of code, calculate the correlation between `imd` and `sum` for each, and then create an intermediate datastructure to hold the correlation values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've apparently understood the question differently than the others. IIUC, what you want is, per `code` value, treat the other two columns as vectors, and find their correlation coefficient. This would be something like:

```
import numpy as np

>>> df.groupby(df.code).apply(lambda g: np.corrcoef(g.imd.values, g['sum'].values)[0][1]).sort_values()
code
10101   -0.955634
10102   -0.936554
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) the `code` column, then apply the correlation based on `imd` and `sum` column as shown below:

```
df
Out[6]: 
    imd   code       sum
0     1  10101   1048171
1     2  10101    911003
2     3  10101    852023
3     4  10101    790893
4     5  10101    923344
5     6  10101    681473
6     7  10101    600303
7     8  10101    497439
8     9  10101    496209
9    10  10101    388457
10    1  10102  26284506
11    2  10102  23567345
12    3  10102  24933988
13    4  10102  22762737
14    5  10102  23205722
15    6  10102  21874259
16    7  10102  21604496
17    8  10102  16723338
18    9  10102  17691183
19   10  10102  15202808

df.groupby('code')[['imd','sum']].corr()
Out[7]: 
                imd       sum
code                         
10101 imd  1.000000 -0.955634
      sum -0.955634  1.000000
10102 imd  1.000000 -0.936554
      sum -0.936554  1.000000
```